# Create another instance of a dynamically loaded class - Java

Tags: java, classloader

So I have created an instance of a class by searching through jar files with no problems, I have it set to create an instance using c.newInstance()  (Is instance the right word to use here?)

Later on in the program I may want to create another instance of that class if a certain event occurs.  How can I go about creating this without having to search through all of the Jar files until I find the right one and then creating it again?  Is there a way to create it somehow if I still have a reference to the first one?

Please assume that I do not know the name of the classes that will be loaded until runtime and there will be multiple classes that will be loaded.

Thanks

Comment: Haha, 3 people all with the correct answer.  How do I choose?

Comment: do you find yourself referring to a particular one as you form the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "x" is the object you created ...

```
x.getClass().newInstance();
```

Answer (score 4):

Save  a reference to the Class of your object

```
Class c = dynamicObject.getClass();
```

and

and you can create a new instance like this (assuming there is a parameterless constructor)

```
Object anotherDynamicObject = c.newInstance(); // you can cast accordingly
```

else, say there is a consturctor that takes int, you can do

```
Constructor constructor = c.getConstructor(int.class);
Object anotherDynamicObject = constructor.newInstance(1);
```